# ASP.NET MVC ActionFilter is not preventing other filters from running

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

I read everywhere that setting context.Result to a non-null value will prevent other filters in the same class from running, but it doesn't work this way for me. The following results in a redirect loop between the two filters:

Global.asax, in `Application_Start()`:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new FilterA(), 1);
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new FilterB(), 2);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

FilterA:

```
public class FilterA : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (long thing that evaluates to true)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Foo/Bar");
        }
    }
}
```

FilterB:

```
public class FilterB : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (...also true, but shouldn't run...)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Foo/Baz");
        }
    }
}
```

I must be missing something... I've tried running `base.OnActionExecuting(context)` both before and after I set Result, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: I would assume, these filters will evaluate false for Foo/Bar and Foo/Baz ... Otherwise you will be in a redirect loop

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The filters don't evaluate to anything. Both the if statements evaluate to true, and the context.Result is set for both. That logic is correct, however only one of the filters should be running, and the second one should not, which is resulting in the redirect loop. From what I read, FilterA setting Result should prevent FilterB from running.

Comment: I'm not sure about filters running, but it would stop the action executing. Have you tried adding a test on each filter to see if result is not null and then just returning from the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This results in a redirect loop probably because your logic in the filters is not excluding requests for `"Foo/Bar"` and `"Foo/Baz"`. Basically setting the result on `FilterA` is preventing the other filter from running *in that request* and returning a redirect, but `FilterB` is getting executed on the *next* request after the redirect.

The following works for me in a new MVC5 application:

```
public class FilterA : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller").Equals("account", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) //long condition evaluating to true
            //logic controlling these filters dont apply to Foo/Bar and Foo/Baz
            && (!context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller").Equals("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                || (!context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").Equals("Bar", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    && !context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").Equals("Baz", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                )
            )
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Foo/Bar");
        }
    }
}

public class FilterB : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (true /*long condition evaluating to true*/
            //logic controlling these filters dont apply to Foo/Bar and Foo/Baz
            && (!context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller").Equals("Foo", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                || (!context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").Equals("Bar", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    && !context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action").Equals("Baz", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                )
            )
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Foo/Baz");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added some logic (you may probably want to refactor it) to both filters that makes sure that the current controller is not the `Foo` controller, or in case the current controller is `Foo` then the actions may be different from `Bar` and `Baz`.

This should prevent a loop where the filter `FilterA` redirects to `~/Foo/Bar`, then the new request is intercepted by `FilterB` that redirects to `~/Foo/Baz` which will be intercepted again by `FilterA` and so on.

As an example, if you create a new MVC5 application with those filters, if you go to `~/`, you are redirected to `~/Foo/Bar` by `FilterA`. However if you go to `~/Account/Login`, you are redirected to `~/Foo/Baz` by `FilterB`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I actually figured this out by myself, but this is exactly what my confusion was. Thanks! :)